Saving a contact created curly brackets around the display name
I'm editing contacts in 5.78, Drupal 7, no extensions, no components.
If I edit a contact, on save, the display name has curly brackets.
So John Smith becomes { John Smith } and displays thus wherever the display name is shown.
Same when creating a new contact. Tried on php 7.4 to 8.3.

Check if there are any spaces between the brackets and tokens in the Individual Display Name Format section of Display Preferences - /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Cheers @Anil that fixed it

Anil - can you add that as an Answer

Check if there are any spaces between the brackets and tokens in the Individual Display Name Format section of Display Preferences - /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1
